# Why won't my KendoUI Grid Sort in my ASP.NET Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kendo-ui

When I try to sort my grid, I get the following error:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnName''

In this particular setup, what I have done is returned all the database table column names to a `List` of type `object` and returned that to the data source.  I've then created a pseudo `Id` column that I wanted the grid to use in its schema for sorting.  However, it makes no difference as the error is telling me that the object doesn't seem to have the `ColumnName` property to sort against.

Here is the code for my grid.

```
<kendo-grid name="columnGrid">
    <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Ajax" page-size="20" server-filtering="true" server-operation="true">
    <transport>
            <read url="/Core/ReadVesselColumns" />
        </transport>
        <schema>
            <model id="Id">
                <fields>
                    <field name="Id" editable="false" />
                </fields>
            </model>
        </schema>
    </datasource>
    <pageable page-size="10" />
    <filterable enabled="true" />
    <sortable enabled="true" />
    <scrollable enabled="true" />
    <columns>
        <column selectable="true" width="50" />
        <column field="ColumnName" title="Column" />
        <column field="ColumnType" title="Type" hidden="true" />                                        
    </columns>
</kendo-grid>
```

Here is the action for the data:

```
public JsonResult ReadVesselColumns([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        //Access Entity Type
        var entityType = _context.Model.FindEntityType("Hagland.Data.Vessel");

        //Create a list to store the column names and types
        var columns = new List<object>();
        int colId = new int();

        //Iterate over the results and populate list
        foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
        {
            columns.Add(new
            {
                Id = colId ++,
                ColumnName = property.GetColumnName(),
                ColumnType = property.GetColumnType()
            });
        };            

        //Return list
        var result = columns.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result);
    }
```

Normally this wouldn't be a problem as I'd be pulling structured data from a database but in this instance, I have a requirement to pull the column names and return to them to the grid for selection.  Is there something I'm doing wrong? Do I need to rework my list setup?

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to schema/model, your model has got only field 'Id'. You need to define fields ColumnName and ColumnType too.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was due to the lack of a model to back it up.  I was trying to be a little too abstracted and as a result, the grid couldn't sort the data.  The solution was to create a model to match the data I was binding to the grid and this allowed the data to be sorted.

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class PositionColumns
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public string ColumnType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As a result of using a model, the list type also had to change to suit it. So, I changed it from `List<object>` to `List<ModelClass>` as below:

```
var columns = new List<PositionColumns>
            {
                new PositionColumns {Id = 1, ColumnName = "Some Name", ColumnType = "string" },
                ...
                ...
            }
```